# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while getting property value

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Below code causes `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to get an object's property value that's fetched during runtime

```
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(myClass, &count);
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(properties[i]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([object respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propertyName)]) {
        id value = [object valueForKey:propertyName];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to guard `valueForKey` from `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: Error message in console?

Comment: No errors displayed in console

Comment: Do you know what the property is that it's choking on? What about properties that don't return an object, but instead return some other type of value?

Comment: For example, 'debugDescription' on some 'CALayer' objects.

Comment: `@property` (and Objective-C, in general) diverged from the original intent of introspection based programming sometime in the early 90s.   This kind of code-- dynamic introspection of the runtime to determine capability and invoke code arbitrarily -- is rife with issues and will result in an unmaintainable mess of instability.   Certainly, an interesting educational pursuit, but not something that should be pursued in a production system (beyond limited debugging role).